# Cocos2D 2.0 different behavior compared to 1.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have several apps created with Cocos2D.

I am upgrading some of them to the new release 2.0 of Cocos2D. The method I am using is:

1. I create a new blank project from the standard template
2. I move all files to the new project

I generally keep the layer Helloworld as my initial Layer. I have noticed that Cocos2D creates an introLayer as the initial one and I have removed that and reverted the behavior to load Helloworld as before. Said that, I have noticed a few things:

1. The behavior inside Helloworld's init method is now different. I have noticed that the orientation is now reported incorrectly inside the init method. It will always report it as portrait even if the app is just landscape. What I have noticed also is that it is like the director is not fully initialized yet. This was confirmed if I try to use the director's view. This view will always come as not valid, if I try to use it inside Helloworld's init method.

To solve that, I have moved all code to Helloworld's onEnter method. Now, Helloworld and the director are full initialized and everything works.

This method worked for the first apps that I upgraded for Cocos2D 1.0 to 2.0, but something is wrong for the application I am converting now from Cocos2D 2.0beta to 2.0 final.

The problem I have now is that Helloworld is not triggering any touch and yes, I have this in place:

```
-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
}


- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return YES;
}
```

What can be preventing Helloworld from detecting touches in 2.0? How can I make the init method of Helloworld to behave like in 2.0 beta or 1.0?

NOTE: ccTouchBegan and registerWithTouchDispatcher are never called when Helloworld loads.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this question is to put [super onEnter] on the onEnter method.

```
-(void) onEnter {
    [super onEnter];
    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
}
```

the lack of this line was creating all kind of problems on the application, like scheduler not working, weird behavior of ccMove, ccTransition not triggering onEnterTransitionDidFinish and all kind of problems.

Answer (score 3):

The rotation issue is a known bug. The very first scene will be initialized in portrait mode, even if the app is set to be in landscape only. That's because the init happens before the orientation has been updated by the app delegate. Putting the code in onEnter fixes that, or simply loading an "intro" scene that then loads the actual first scene fixes that as well.

The touch issue is probably not a problem of cocos2d 2.0. Maybe it's as simple as not setting `self.isTouchEnabled = YES`. If the registerWithTouchDispatcher method isn't called, then isTouchEnabled is not set to YES or you're not doing this in a CCLayer class but maybe CCScene.

Comment: I discovered now that I have to put this on onEnter: [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];  for some reason registerWithTouchDispatcher is not called automatically anymore inside Helloworld. Another thing is that now I have to put CCTargetedTouchDelegate on the interface's delegate declaration of Helloworld. After doing this, ccTouchBegan is now being triggered. and now I have to do that for all classes that support touch... Is this a bug?

Comment: and yes, I am doing it on a CClayer class. Helloworld as it is created by the default template. I have discovered a lot of other problems now and I will be probably keeping the project using 2.0 beta until 2.0 is fixed. Anyway, thanks.